# create an executable with custom msgs

Tags: ros, catkin, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to create a ros executable that uses a custom msg. I used catkin to make a package with a custom message. I ran catkin_make and copied the executable to another location the node seems to run fine (I put in print statements that are continuously executing). The topic I'm publishing is part of the rostopic list but when a rostopic echo mytopic results in the following:
ERROR: Cannot load message class for mynode/mycustommsg. Are your messages built?

a rosmsg show mycustommsg shows the msg.

What should I be doing ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70204/create-an-executable-with-custom-msgs/) by [canatan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3563/canatan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you are in the same environment for both rosmsg and rostopic.

And be careful about copying executables around.  Many use shared libs and need the environment in which they were either built or isntalled.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0